# android app particular java file used

Tags: android, security, reverse-engineering

How can i know which java file is used at the current time at that current interface. I know we can do this with a logcat when we know the source code , we can make everything log.i and stuff. but what happens when we don't know the source code or while assessing a black box android app

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to the files how you supposed to know which file you are getting?

The best way to achieve what you want is to use a decompiler in your APK and do a debug.

http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Comment: We can debug and suppose there is only java file which doesnt do ssl pinning but the rest of all the app does?  How can i get to that point? I cant fire burp suite because there is only one java file which does not but the rest of the app does.